# Android: Rotating display causes camera preview to go black

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I have code which is used to rotate and scale a `SurfaceView` when the orientation changes. The issue I am having, is that when I rotate the display `this.setRotation(*degrees*);` the preview turns black. I am unsure why this is the case.

```
public class VideoSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        int videoWidth = this.getCamera().getParameters().getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo().width;
        int videoHeight = this.getCamera().getParameters().getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo().height;

        float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)_appContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        // Get the width of the screen
        int screenWidth = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int screenHeight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;

        // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = this.getLayoutParams();
        if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
            lp.width = screenWidth;
            lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
        } else {
            lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
            lp.height = screenHeight;
        }
        // Commit the layout parameters
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //The following lines cause the preview to go black
        Display display = ((WindowManager) _appContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            this.setRotation(90);
        } else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            this.setRotation(180);
        }

        _camera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

Comment: which device is that?

Comment: It is a Nexus 7 tablet.

Comment: [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) does not have `setRotation()` method. It is inherited from `View`, and not relevant here. Use `Camera.setOrientation()`.